# How to add TypeScript types to request body in Next.js API route?

Tags: typescript, next.js

#### Problem

One of the primary reasons I like using TypeScript is to check that I am passing correctly typed params to given function calls.

However, when using Next.js, I am running into the issue where params passed to a Next.js API endpoint end up losing their types when the are "demoted" to the `NextApiRequest` type.

Typically, I would pull off params doing something like `req.body.[param_name]` but that entire chain has type `any` so I lose any meaningful type information.

#### Example

Let's assume I have an API endpoint in a Next.js project at `pages/api/add.ts` which is responsible for adding two numbers. In this file, we also have a typed function for adding two numbers, that the API endpoint will call.

```js
const add = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const result = add(req.body.number_one, req.body.number_two);
    res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(403).json({ err: "Error!" });
  }
};
```

The problem I am running into, and what I would like help with, is how to type `req.body.number_one` and `req.body.number_two` or any sort of param coming off of the request object. Is this possible?

Since the types off of the request object are `any` TypeScript does not complain, even if you try calling the API endpoint with incorrectly typed params.

```js
fetch("/api/add", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ number_one: 1, number_two: "two" }),
});
```

The TypeScript compiler will have no problems with the above call to the API endpoint, even though the types are incorrect. It treats the `body` as an `any` type, so it loses any type information.

It would be great if I could type params cast from the request body being sent to API endpoints in Next.js

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can create a new interface that extends `NextApiRequest` and adds the typings for the two fields.

```js
interface ExtendedNextApiRequest extends NextApiRequest {
  body: {
    number_one: number;
    number_two: number;
  };
}
```

Then use it to type the `req` object in the handler function.

```js
export default async (req: ExtendedNextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    //...
};
```

---

While extending the `NextApiRequest` type will stop TypeScript from complaining, it does not prevent potential runtime errors from occurring.

For a better, type-safe approach that narrows down the types instead, check out [@Matthieu Gellé's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70788003/1870780).

Answer (score 16):

Just make a **Type Guard** and use it within your handler.
Matthieu's answer is great but nasty when having many expected properties.

Checking if something sent through the body is of some type can take quite a lot of time when you find yourself going through 5+ properties. Even worse headaches if those are nested multiple levels. Just use proper validators and write schemas for them.

For this purpose, as Matthieu specified, you shouldn't extend `NextApiRequest` and `NextApiResponse` by overriding existing properties, only extend them to add additional ones.

Instead, I'd write a generic like this:

```
function isValidBody<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  body: any,
  fields: (keyof T)[],
): body is T {
  return Object.keys(body).every((key) => fields.includes(key))
}
```

And use it like this:

```
type RequestBody = {
  id: string
}

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (!isValidBody<RequestBody>(req.body, ['id'])) {
    return res.status(402)
  }

  // req.body.id - is expected to be a string down the road
}
```

*Reference:* [Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: 100% the best answer here. Duck typing down properties is quite egregious especially when you have many objects in a request body. Thanks for the effort here for everybody!

Comment: this doesn't actually check each key's type though. `RequestyBody.id` could be a string, number, object, etc. & isValidBody would be true.

Comment: @BigRon - That is correct. It only checks for presence of the properties in the body.

Answer (score 14):

julio's answer works but it is not encouraged by the official documentation :
[Extending the req/res objects with TypeScript](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#extending-the-reqres-objects-with-typescript)

```
const add = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { body } = req;
  try {
    if (
      "number_one" in body &&
      typeof body.number_one === "number" &&
      "number_two" in body &&
      typeof body.number_two === "number"
    ) {
      const result = add(body.number_one, body.number_two);
      return res.status(200).json(result);
    }
    throw new Error("number_one or number_two is not a number");
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(403).json({ err: "Error!" });
  }
};
```

I haven't modified your code much so that you can integrate it easily, if you have the courage to come and modify this brick despite the fact that it "works"

Answer (score 6):

In case you'd also like to add `types` to `NextApiResponse`

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [@dvlden answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914813/12057872) is almost perfect, but as it was pointed out it doesn't actually check each key's type.

I think the better approach is to use zod to check if data is valid.

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const bodySchema = z.object({
  number_one: z.number(),
  number_two: z.number(),
})

type Body = z.infer<typeof bodySchema>

function isValidBody(body: any): body is Body {
  const { success } = bodySchema.safeParse(body)
  return success
}
```

And use it like this

```
async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (!isValidBody(req.body)) {
    return res.status(402)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming in a bit late, but I had a similar issue for the request query params. I got this working and I believe it's still type safe. Just adds some auto-complete and code-level documentation to *intended* available parameters: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36373

Should be easily modified to support body as well

Comment: Please include the relevant code snippets here.

Comment: Your solution makes sense in the type space. But aware that it will have no effect at runtime. It's easy to create the illusion that just because it's typed, you will have the data in the right shape. You still need to validate the input to ensure it's schema.

Comment: Btw isn't your solution the same as the accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69895731/73603

Answer (score 1):

Note: I’m one of the maintainers of Remult

If you can live with another dependency, with [Remult](https://github.com/remult/remult) you use type-safe code for all your API calls (CRUD for TypeScript models and RPC for functions).

Your `add` function would look like this:

```
// utils.ts
import { BackendMethod } from "remult";

export class ApiUtils {
   @BackendMethod({ allowed: true })
   static async add(a: number, b: number) {
      return a + b;
   }
}
```

and you'd import it in the frontend and call it directly:

```
// App.tsx
import { ApiUtils } from 'utils'

alert(await ApiUtils.add(1,2));
```

Remult will send the `POST` request, handle it on the Next.js API route, and pass the values to the `add` function on the backend.

There's a [Next.js tutorial](https://remult.dev/tutorials/react-next/) if you want to explore further.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is that you both need a solution to ensure type safety and have runtime validation of the data. As [@dvlden pointed it out, using type guards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914813/73603) will provide both, it's a common practice to achieve this goal. However, it can be quite cumbersome in more complext scenarios.

Another tool that can help the OP's dilema is [Zod, a TypeScript-first schema validation library](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod). It makes sure your data has the right shape and if so, provides correct types too.

```js
const Body = z.object({
    number_one: z.number(),
    number_two: z.number(),
});

type Body = z.infer<typeof Body>;

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const result = Body.safeParse(req.body);
    if (result.success) {
        console.log(result.data) // type is Body, TS is happy
    });
    // ...
}
```

I used to work with Elm in the past and Zod's approach is very similar to Elm's in which for each HTTP requests you must provide a [JSON decoder that parses the input data](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/json.html) in the right typed value or returns an error if cannot succeed. I mention this because I consider Elm's implementation a standard in terms of simplicity and yet guarantee of safety.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a mix of TS and yup to enforce type safety in next.  Validations will occur before any logic is executed.  It's a bit wordy, but it should give you what you want in both type safety and data validity.

```
export interface NextApiRequestQueryBody<TQuery = any, TBody = any> extends NextApiRequest {
  query: TQuery;
  body: TBody;
  yup: YupRequest;
}
```

An example implementation would look something like this.

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

export interface UserRequestQuery {
  id: number;
}

export interface UserRequestBody {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface UserResponse {
  token: string
}

const schema = {
  GET: yup.object().shape({
     id: yup.number().required(),
  }),
  POST: yup.object().shape({
    id: yup.number().required(),
    username: yup.string().required(),
    password: yup.string().required(),
  }),
};

export default async (
  req: NextApiRequestQueryBody<UserRequestQuery, UserRequestBody>,
  res: NextApiResponse<UserResponse>,
) => {
  req.yup = schema;
  await useValidate(req, res);

  // rest of your logic, if validations pass
}
```

Then you can create a validation hook middleware to validate your yup schema, or copy the code out from the middleware straight into your api logic.

```
export const useValidate = createMiddleware(async (req: NextApiRequestQueryBody, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { yup } = req;

    yup[req.method] && yup[req.method].validateSync({ ...req.query, ...req.body });
  } catch (e: any) {
    return badRequest(res, e.message);
  }

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way extending dvlden's and Augusto Oliveira's answers:

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { z } from 'zod'

// file1.ts

function isValidBody<T extends z.ZodSchema>(
  body: any,
  schema: T
): body is z.infer<T> {
  const { success } = schema.safeParse(body)
  return success
}

// file2.ts

const bodySchema = z.object({
  number_one: z.number().optional(),
  number_two: z.number(),
})

export const POST = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  if (!isValidBody(req.body, bodySchema)) {
    // Handle invalid body here.
    return
  }

  const number_two = req.body.number_two

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think we can use [express-validator](https://yaali4422519.medium.com/next-js-validate-request-using-next-connect-and-express-validator-464997067a9c) validate the body before use it.

Then a simple method can used from the [Extending the req/res objects with TypeScript](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#extending-the-reqres-objects-with-typescript)

```js
type ExtendedRequest = NextApiRequest & {
  body: {
    number_one: number;
    number_two: number;
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Had this issue as well! Ended up defining the body object and passing it into fetch with an interface for for what the req body in the api

In the case of your example --

```
pages/api/add.ts

    export interface addBody {
       number_one:number;
       number_two:number
    }

    export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
      try {
        const result = add(req.body.number_one, req.body.number_two);
        res.status(200).json(result);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(403).json({ err: "Error!" });
      }
    };
```

and for where you call fetch --

```
import { addBody } from "pages/api/add.ts";

    const body:addBody = { number_one: 1, number_two: "two" }

    fetch("/api/add", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
```

Ended up working for me and typescript throws an error when I don't have all the params I'd like. Hope this helps!

Comment: but `req.body` isn't typed using `addBody`, it's just 
`Partial<{[key: string]: string | string[];}>;`

Comment: `req.body` is still `any`