# how to strongly type body of NextApiRequest in Nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js

wondering how to define the type of body of an API POST Nextjs route in order to benefit from typesafety ?
In the NextApiRequest, body is defined as "any" and NextApiRequest is not generic

using as force the type but this is not clean at all

running NextJs12 and typescript 4.4.4

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

interface IBody {
  test: string;
  value: number;
}

const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest, <-- whish to have something here like NextApiRequest<TQuery, TBody,..>
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> => {
  const { body } = req;
  console.log(body as IBody); <--this is not safe at all

  res.status(200).json({ text: "Hello" });
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add TypeScript types to request body in Next.js API route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893369/how-to-add-typescript-types-to-request-body-in-next-js-api-route)

Comment: it does. thks q lot

Answer (score 6):

You can use TypeScript `Omit` to replace the body of the request with a custom type.

```
type Override<T1, T2> = Omit<T1, keyof T2> & T2;
    
export type MyCustomRequest = Override<NextApiRequest, { body: MyCustomRequestBody }>
    
export type MyCustomRequestBody = {
  myCustomField: string
}
```