# NextJS API Request Query params with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm building a REST API with NextJS and I'm wondering how to make the query parameters for one of my endpoints type-safe with TypeScript.

The endpoint I am currently working on is used to validate the uniqueness of a users' email when signing up: `/api/users/validate-email`, and I am sending an email string as a query parameter like this: `/api/users/validate-email?email=someEmail@email.com`.

Inside of the endpoint handler, I access the email from the query parameters as follows:

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { email } = req.query;
};

export default handler;
```

However, with this setup de-structuring `email` from `req.query` is not type-safe and this is where I am stuck.

I have come up with a solution by extending the `NextApiRequest` type as follows:

```
type NextApiRequestValidateEmail = NextApiRequest & {
    query: {
        email: string;
    }   
}

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequestValidateEmail, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { email } = req.query;
};

export default handler;
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's the recommended way to do this and I can't seem to find anything about this in the documentation. So I am asking if this is the proper approach and if not, how does one go about declaring a type for an endpoints query parameters?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: While you can extend the `NextApiRequest` type like you did, it's better to narrow down the types to avoid runtime errors. See [How to add TypeScript types to request body in Next.js API route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893369/how-to-add-typescript-types-to-request-body-in-next-js-api-route).

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you. What about something in between? If you create a custom interface that extends the `NextApiRequest`, but also do a runtime check 
to confirm that the `email` is indeed in the params object and is of type string in the handler?

Comment: That's completely fine too.